# GCP Storage for large temporary data

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform

I'm using a Cloud SQL instance to store two types of data: typical transactional data and large "read-only" data. Each of these read-only tables could have GBs of data and they work like snapshots that are refreshed once a day. The old data is totally replaced by the most recent data. The "read-only" tables reference data from the "transactional tables", but I don't necessarily need to perform joins between them, so they're kind of "independent".

In this context, I believe using Cloud SQL to store these kind of tables are going to be a problem in terms of billing. Because Cloud SQL is fully managed, I would be paying for maintenance work from Google and I wouldn't need any kind of maintenance for those specific tables.

Maybe there are databases more suitable for storing snapshot/temporary data. I'm considering to move those type of tables to another kind of storage, but it's possible that I would end up making the bill even higher. Or maybe I could continue using Cloud SQL for those tables and just unlog them.

Can anyone help me with this? Is there any kind of storage in GCP that would be great for storing large snapshots that are refreshed once a day? Or is there an workaround to make Cloud SQL not maintain those tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough question because there are a lot of options and a lot of things that could work. The GCP documentation page "[Choosing a Storage Option](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/)" is very handy in this kind of cases. It has a flowchart to select a storage option based on the kind of data you want to store, a video that explains each storage option and a table with the description, strong points and use cases for each option. I would recommend to start there.

Also, if the issue with Cloud SQL is that is fully managed and pricy, you can [set up MySQL on Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql) and manage it yourself. Is also fairly cheaper for the same machine. For a n1-standard-1, [$0.0965 in Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#2nd-gen-instance-pricing) and [$0.0475 in GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#predefined) (keep in mind that other charges may apply on top of the machine price)